# How can i get the time to update without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html

So the code/script is below. I want it to update without having to refresh the page. I tried putting it in a loop but the page just never loaded. Can anyone help?
Thanks

```js
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = (("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2)) + "." + (("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)) + "." + (dt.getFullYear()) + " " + (("0" + dt.getHours()).slice(-2)) + ":" + (("0" + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2)) + ":" + (("0" + dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2)) + ":" + (("0" + dt.getMilliseconds()).slice(-2));
setinterval(timer, 1000);
```

Comment: Apologies the setinterval(time,1000); isnt supposed to be there as it doesnt work
code:

<script>
            
            var dt = new Date();
            document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = (("0"+dt.getDate()).slice(-2)) +"."+ (("0"+(dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)) +"."+(dt.getFullYear()) +" "+ (("0"+dt.getHours()).slice(-2)) +":"+ (("0"+dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2)) +":"+ (("0"+dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2)) +":"+ (("0"+dt.getMilliseconds()).slice(-2));
            
        </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code like this

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = (("0"+dt.getDate()).slice(-2)) +"."+ (("0"+(dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)) +"."+(dt.getFullYear()) +" "+ (("0"+dt.getHours()).slice(-2)) +":"+ (("0"+dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2)) +":"+ (("0"+dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2)) +":"+ (("0"+dt.getMilliseconds()).slice(-2));
}, 1);
```

```html
<div id="datetime">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
  h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock